# Getting minimum values and index from a matrix without repeating index C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a `vector< vector <int> >` matrix of size n and I want to get the minimum value for each i and it indexs [i][j] and put it on a vector but I don't want to get any indexs repeated.

I've found a theoretical way but I cannot write it in code.

Make 2 vectors U←{1,...,n}, L←{1,...,n}
Repeat n times

- Be (u,l)∈U×L from matrix[u,l] ≤ matrix[i,j], ∀i∈U, ∀j∈L
- S[u] ← l
- Do U←U-{u} y L←L-{l}

Comment: Your question is not very clear: you want to find the value and the position of the minimum element in the matrix (min and argmin)? Or what?

Comment: For each column I want the row index of the minimum element, but in the next column I don't want to repeat row index previously selected.

Comment: @Trouner So in the next column, if the min element is at the same row, you want the 2nd smallest element ?

Comment: Exactly. That the expected behaviour. What I do now is adding +1 on the value but that modifies the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code this algorithm directly

```
typedef vector<vector<int>> Matrix;
typedef pair<size_t, size_t> Index;
typedef vector<Index> IndexList;

IndexList MinimalSequence(const Matrix& matrix) {
    IndexList result;

    set<size_t> U, L;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i) { // consider square
        U.insert(i);
        L.insert(i);
    }

    while (U.size()) { // same as L.size()
        int min = numeric_limits<int>::max();
        Index minIndex;
        for (auto u: U)
            for (auto l: L)
                if (matrix[u][l] < min) {
                    minIndex = make_pair(u, l);
                    min = matrix[u][l];
                }

        U.erase(minIndex.first);
        L.erase(minIndex.second);
        result.push_back(minIndex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

also your question is not clear in this way: do you want to start from the overall smallest element of the matrix (as your formula said) and then move to the next smallest? 
or do you want to move through the columns from left to right? I implemented it according to formulas.

Note that set of non-negative integers in your formula is `set<size_t>` on which insert() and erase() are available. For all is while-loop

I would also suggest to try alternative algorithm - sort a list of matrix indices by there corresponding values and then iterate over it removing indices you dont want anymore.

edit: code actually differs from algorithm in few ways to be precise. That seemed more practical.

- process is repeated until set of indices is exhausted - that is equal to n
- return structure is list of 2d indices and encodes more information than array

Answer (score 1):

You already have accepted an answer, but aren't you facing the [Assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) that can be solved using the [Hugarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), and maybe even more efficient algorithms that exists and are already implemented?